# Unity 3D Raycast not going in the right direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, raycasting

i wrote some code that is supposed to emit a raycast from the gameobject shoulder and goes through the gameobject hand. this is to give the direction that the mouse is so if my character picks up an item they could used that item in that direction, ie gun shoots in that direction. currently i only have it drawing the cast to debug it because the cast emits from the correct position but does not go through the hand. ive tried multiple iterations of this code based on the answers of previous question but it doesn't seem to work. the game is a 2.5D side scroller.

```
    pos.x = transform.position.x;
    pos.y = transform.position.y -1.4f;
    pos1.x = shoulder.transform.position.x;
    pos1.y = shoulder.transform.position.y;
    pos1.z = 15f;
    pos.z =0f;
    RaycastHit info;
    Debug.DrawRay(pos1, pos, Color.yellow);
```

the code is on the hand gameobject, it also does strange things when i move the charter from the orgin , like flip directions and only rotates halfway and doesn't emit the raycast in the opposite direction.

Comment: `DrawRay(Vector3 start, Vector3 dir, Color color)` the function takes a position vector and rotation vector, it doesn't draw a line between two position vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the vectors you previously had:

```
// Hand
pos.x = transform.position.x;
pos.y = transform.position.y -1.4f;
pos.z = 0f;

// Shoulder
pos1.x = shoulder.transform.position.x;
pos1.y = shoulder.transform.position.y;
pos1.z = 15f;
```

Substract the hand vector from the shoulder vector to get the distance (or delta) between the two points.

```
Vector3 dir = pos1 - pos;

// For bonus point you can set the length of the ray by using dir as a unit vector
public float length;

dir = dir.normalized * length;
```

And finally feed the position of the shoulder and the new direction vector containing the direction and length of your ray to your function.

```
Debug.DrawRay(pos1, dir, Color.yellow);
```

Comment: Thank You, since my game is 2.5d i had to set the z pos for both shoulder and hand vectors to the plane i have everything on, also the length addition is very smart, i could use this for shooting distance.